# How to unset Shipping Method and tax on Checkout page refresh In Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

If I add a product which have tax based on shipping address in magento then magento shows tax in review table on checkout page after filling shipping form.

But when I refresh the checkout page then tax (calculated before page refresh) still shown there in review table regardless shipping address. I want to recalculate all review table data on checkout page refresh. How Can I do this.?

Also see my this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61955/how-to-set-tax-amount-to-zero-on-checkout-page-refresh